# POST in cURL lib with PHP isn't sending

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to send POSTDATA via cURL with PHP and i think post isn't sending

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$t = curl_exec($ch);
```

Don't know why, but i'm trying to login in a page and when i dump $t, i always see the form, curl_error is empty, what can i do to  debug this? the page trying to login isn't mine!

---

I have a local form emulating cURL and its OK:

```
<form action="$url" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="$uspw" />
  <input type="hidden" name="password" value="$uspw" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

It login in the $url! Here is the $data i send to POSTFIELDS in cURL

```
$data = array('username' => $uspw,
              'password' => $uspw);
```

Yes.. the user and password is the same

---

Headers received:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 25 Nov 2012 05:23:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie"
Content-Length: 4822
Set-Cookie: SESSIONID_portalApp=xxxxxx!-xxx!xxx; path=/
Content-Language: en
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

and after this i receive all the form, again...

---

```
$data = array('username' => $uspw,
    'password' => $uspw);


$header = array('Origin: xxx',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
        'Except:',
        'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8',
        );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'xxx.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'xxxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$t = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thank You!

Comment: You haven't shown the data you are trying to send. And what is this site you are trying to log into? My guess is that if you are getting the form back you may not even be using the right URL. But without the URL, I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: i can't say public the url, is very private, thanks for the negative btw.

If this help, i have a local form emulating the form from the URL and in action i use the same URL as cURL, and when i press submit in my local form, it login

in the data have something like this: `array('username' => $usr, 'password' => $pw);` nothing more

Comment: Debugging is done by setting: CURLOPT_VERBOSE to true.

Comment: I will remove the downvote if you put the information I ask for in the question. Can you at least show us the local form you have working. You can change the action that's fine.

Comment: edited with something now, this is all i can say dude...

well. another thing is.. when i submit, i think the 3rd page send me to another page, doing header locations, but dunnno

Comment: Maybe if it needs to follow redirects: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Comment: just now i try this and nothing :S i see the FORM without error, if you put a false user or password, it sends an error and didn't see in the data i give, i only see the form :S very strange

Comment: And did you set user agent in the header?

Comment: i put the headers I receive in the question

Comment: Guys, he's _logging in_ to something .. cookies anyone?

Comment: Can you show us the headers that you are sending? $header?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to login to a third party system without a browser.

It's extremely likely that this isn't working because you're not doing something that it expects, which is establishing a session cookie. Though you might be logging in *correctly*, the remote site is probably showing you the form again because nothing in your cookie is telling it to do otherwise upon redirection. The headers explain this:

> Set-Cookie: SESSIONID_portalApp=xxxxxx!-xxx!xxx; path=/

Create a cookie file for cURL to use (using something like [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/tempnam)) and tell cURL where it lives using the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` directive. You could also grab an existing cookie from your browser and try, as an additional way to troubleshoot.

Add this prior to initializing cURL:

```
$cookieFile = tempnam('/dev/shm', 'curlCookie_');
```

Then tell cURL to use it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
```

I suggested `/dev/shm` because it's obliterated across reboots, you could create it anywhere you have the ability to do so. Just take care to remove them when no longer needed. You can also change the prefix to make the individual files easier to associate with individual requests (timestamp, PID, etc), handy for debugging.

Also make sure that you set the user agent string to something known to be acceptable to the remote site. Remember, it expects a browser - so you have to be sure you behave like one. Setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` true is probably a good idea, as suggested in comments.

If that doesn't work, do the action normally in a browser and look at the pages closely. It could be that JS is required in order for a session to be properly constructed .. at which point you're kind of out of luck just using cURL.

Comment: thank you for the answer! i try this but nothing new, i see in chrome, if i join to the page, this cookie is always created and when i'm login, another variable is setted and i didn't receive this new varible

Comment: Hmm, it's really hard to speculate then without being able to reproduce it. Not having cookies enabled was _definitely_ part of your problem, the question now is .. why aren't you receiving the second variable. Did you set the user agent string / etc accordingly? What is your code doing that chrome doesn't? Is JS required for this second variable to be set?

Comment: i think yes, i see headers sents by chrome and my script and are the sames :S

Comment: Check the page source, If you've got the headers matching then I bet you have some JS to deal with, which means kicking off a second request to the AJAX endpoint and fiddling with the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header if that's the case.

Comment: @TimPost If his local form works then how can it be javascript that's his problem? I think you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Shouldn't $cookieFile and $curlCookie be the same variable?

Comment: @Codeguy007 Yup, fixed :) If his local form works and he is _redirected_ (from say `/login`) and some XHR request is made to set other cookie values (CSRF, etc), it could explain what he's seeing. While I agree that's insane, I've seen it done frequently.

Comment: just now edited the question with ALL the curl and data, all headers are the same like if i send via chrome, the cookie file only save 1 variable and when im logged i have 2 variables

Comment: I can't help much more unless I am able to reproduce this, which clearly is not possible due to the constraints of your question. My answer was an educated guess, which solved _part_ of the problem .. but we're at the point where we need to just have at it, which clearly is not possible and makes this question _extremely_ localized.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the form page and then, with *same* curl resource do a post request. Also, add the following settings:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "valid user agent");
```

Comment: Why is there one request? there should be two. First to the page with form, second is submit of that form. Remember, with *same* curl resource. Also, add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'xxx.txt');` and keep `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'xxx.txt');`.

Comment: Don't understand, the url before and after submit is the same, i try to do another exec with the same resource and nothing, always the same f.... form XD - btw, in cookie file don't save the cookie when is logged

Comment: if i add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,"sessionCreated=true");`, the exec returns `sesion expires`! is the message from web when sesion expires

Comment: I log into the web, get the header with: `Cookie: `, copy the line and paste in headers to send with curl and .. it functions!! obviously, when the session expires, i need to change the header :S how to do auto?

Comment: What do you mean by "log into"? You can clearly see that the website puts cookies to users and since your file in `COOKIEJAR` and `COOKIEFILE` contains nothing, that is the problem with your requests. Make sure it's valid and writeable, there should be cookies after the requests.

Comment: i get 1 variable in the cookie, but when im login via web, i get 2 variables, cookiejar save a file but only with 1 variable, it seems like POST doesn't send :S

Comment: The second cookie is being given by some file that is accessed by your browser and not accessed by your curl. That can be js or css file. You need browser addon like HttpFox, use it to find which request gives 2nd cookie and then query that url with curl before submiting form.

Comment: Ranty  but, i have a local form with same inputs (hidden) and when i submit the form it accept, i will try httpfox, in a few seconds put the results

Comment: Because your browser already has both cookies from previous requests? Or every time you try you clear all cookies and session data?

Comment: I would try to remove some of your headers, that you are forcing, if some of them are not native, they might cause the problem. But usually theres something simple causing the problem.